# How do I make git commit -a not add submodule changes?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Due to many cases lately of people reverting other people's submodule changes, I've narrowed down the problem to this work flow:

- Programmer A pushes a new submodule revision
- Programmer B performs a `git rebase`, but does not run `git submodules update`, so she's still on the old submodule revision.
- Programmer B finishes making changes, and commits them using `git commit -a`. This adds a revert of programmer A's submodule update.
- Programmer B pushes.

I seem to recall that git used to not grab submodules updates when `commit -a` was used. Regardless of whether I am misremembering or not, as of now (version 2.14.1) it does.

Does anyone know of a way to make git not automatically add submodules to commits?

Comment: There's nothing in git out-of-the-box to prevent that. Your best shot would probably be a post-receive hook on the server that prevents rewinds on submodules.

Comment: Not all git hosts support server side hooks. Also, a push time hook is rather late in the process. I'd rather write `pre-rebase` and `post-rewrite` hooks that rebase the unmodified submodules when you rebase the branch. I was hoping for something that requires less work :-)

Comment: A server side hook is the only thing you can rely on, since client side hooks require programmers to actually enable them. And Programmer B doesn't seem to be so careful.